# Perodic AJAX calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a page where I want to do an AJAX call and possibly render a partial every 30 seconds or so. Now, I know how to do this with jquery AJAX, doing an AJAX call and passing in the path, but it doesn't seem like the Rails way.

I say this because the result is that the main view does not show you the entire structure of the page. When you render a partial, you at least see the partial's positioning inside the document, if you render a partial via AJAX, you have to read the javascript code to know that it's there.

Is there a more unobtrusive (for lack of a better word) way to do this?

Comment: Won't the initial render of the view include the partial the first time through?

Comment: No, not in this case. The first render of the partial will be through the AJAX call, for reasons specific to the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to do something like this, and want the partial block to be positioned, I include a container div that I then render the AJAX call into. That was I can position the partial prior to it actually being rendered.